# Плывёт dataGridView

Tags: c#

Имеется ПО для подсвечивании когда истекла дата, проблема в том что когда запускаешь ПО визуально плывут строки в dataGridView. Как исправить?

Код ниже, если его убрать строки отображаются корректно.

```
 private void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex < 0 || dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow) return;
            var dt = DateTime.Now;
            dt = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, dt.Day, 0, 0, 0);

            if (((DateTime)dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Срок до"].Value).CompareTo(dt) < 0)
                dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Он белый, но если прокрутить колесо мыши он закрашивает на секнуду в красный и сразу сново становится белым.

Comment: А скриншот добавить можете? Сложно понять, о чем речь.

Comment: добавил скриншот

Comment: единственное что нашёл  вот такое исключение Возникло исключение "System.InvalidCastException" в ("Заданное приведение является недопустимым.")

Comment: проверьте тип поля: `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["Срок до"].Value` судя по всему это строка

Comment: Всё перепроверил не могу найти почему он так ведёт себя((

Comment: @Павел, а что если использовать ваш код, только менять свойство BackgroundColor вместо BackColor?

Comment: @Павел и вообще, зачем вы используете событие перед окрашиванием? Оно же постоянно у вас срабатывает при любых телодвижениях в форме. Перенесите ваш код в обработчик события `RowsAdded`

Comment: Полностью убрал событие но осталось также. При старте он 17 строк показывает нормально потом пусто если прокрутить колесо он показывает ниже. Очень похоже что зависает dataGridView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем нашёл проблему, точнее подсказали большое спасибо этому человеку.

Проблема была что в столбце `"Срок до"` были пустые строки из-за этого он не показывал пустые ячейки.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно ваш вариант где то вызывает конфликт. Попробуйте закрашивать через e.Graphics.

```
Rectangle rowBounds = new Rectangle(
    this.dataGridView1.RowHeadersWidth, e.RowBounds.Top,
    this.dataGridView1.Columns.GetColumnsWidth(
        DataGridViewElementStates.Visible) -
    this.dataGridView1.HorizontalScrollingOffset + 1,
    e.RowBounds.Height);

e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), rowBounds);
```

Обратите внимание, текст срезан ровно настолько, насколько торчит снизу неполная ячейка. Эта ячейка закрашивается не полностью (потому что она отображена не полностью). В предложенном мной коде формируется прямоугольник из видимой части строки и он уже закрашивается в нужный цвет. Как то так )

Comment: интересное решение) Только не могу понять как его с DateTime связать((((

Comment: @Павел Да так же в условии. Я только способ раскраски вам подсказал

Comment: Интересно он закрашивает когда я кручу колесо мыши, а так остаётся белым(

Comment: @Павел не понял. у меня нет возможности это протестировать. Можете скрин прислать или подробнее объяснить? )

Comment: добавил скрин что получилось

Answer (score 0):

Может быть попробовать привязаться на событие cellpainting?

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 4)
        {
            if ((e.Value as DateTime?).Value.CompareTo(DateTime.Now) < 0)
                (sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }
```

Comment: тоже также(((((